# How can I bundle my tests which use Sinon.js using Rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, commonjs, rollupjs

I'm using Rollup.js with plugins `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` and `rollup-plugin-commonjs` to bundle my tests, which use Sinon.js. When I try to run the bundled file I get the following error:

> Error: Dynamic requires are not currently supported by rollup-plugin-commonjs

Is there any workaround for this error, or do I have to use some other tool like Webpack?

Comment: What is the purpose of bundling your tests?

Comment: @KennyFellows My tests use ES 6 modules (the `import` syntax), so I couldn't use them in browser without bundling them.

Comment: I don't see this working with `rollup-plugin-commonjs`. If one of the files have a dynamic require it will fail with this error, and if this is in a third party dependency there's nothing you can do. Webpack can handle this and even  more. And if you want tree shaking you could try Webpack 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinon.js v1.x doesn't work with bundlers like Rollup.js. You should upgrade to a newer version (v2.x or later).